# Where is my variable ? objective-c

Tags: objective-c, variables, getter-setter

I initialize a view(Image) through:

```
Image *myImageView = [[Image alloc]init];
    myImageView.myId = randomImageNumber;
    [myImageView initWithImage:myImage];
```

At the Image class I do a Log(LOG1) and get the previously set randomImageNumber.
Later on, in the very same Class, I do a second Log(LOG2).
Why does my second log have no value anymore ?

Here my implementation-file of the Class Image:

```
@synthesize myId;
-(id) initWithImage: (UIImage *) anImage
{
    NSLog(@"LOG1%d",myId);
    if ((self = [super initWithImage:anImage]))
    {
        self.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    }
    return self;
}

}
-(void)touchesBegan...
....
- (void) touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
  NSLog(@"LOG2%d",myId);
}
```

The "return self" empties myId which i declared in the header-file and which was set at the initialisation.
How do I prevent that ?

my Headerfile looks like this:

```
@interface Image : UIImageView 
{
   int myId;
}
@property (assign) int myId;

@end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couple things in your code. NEVER call init more than once on an object, that just screws up your object.

Change it to this:

```
Image *myImageView = [[Image alloc] initWithImage:myImage];
myImageView.myId = randomImageNumber;
```

That is your problem, by default when initializing a subclass of `NSObject`, all properties are set to `0` (or `nil` if they are pointers).

If you need to have a default value for `myId` then do this:

```
// Image.m

@implementation

// other code

-(id) initWithImage:(UIImage *) image
{
    if (self = [super initWithImage:image])
    {
         self.myId = randomImageNumber;
    }

    return self;
}

// other code

@end
```

Comment: Ok, I tried this kind of initialization, but in this case even my first Log didn't give me a value -> just 0 like you said. How could I initialize my Image-Class without loosing my instance-variables declared in the header(of the Image-Class) ?

Comment: @algro The first log *should* give 0. Instance variables are always empty until they're initialised -- they cannot be given a value in the interface, only declared. You should probably post what's in your header file, since it sounds like there is some misunderstanding here.

Comment: ok, I posted my header-file... It doesn't matter if the first log is 0. I need it only if touched -> LOG2. At that point the value should be set no ?

Comment: @algro Yep. Assuming you don't have other calls changing the value, once you've set the property it should remain set.

Comment: But at the moment it doesn't. Shouldn't I somehow alloc the value in the initializing-Class ? I heard Multiple threads / Memory management could be the issue, but I don't know how to implement...

Comment: If you need to have `myId` set to a default value on initialization, then call the code in my edited answer

Comment: Ok I found out that the touched region doesn't correspond with the underlying image

Answer (score 7):

I think I found it:

https://www.google.com/maps/place/Variable/@53.626739,10.025728,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m2!3m1!1s0x47b1885360fab615:0x584b82c7dfb5f612

Can you check if this Variable is yours?

besties
phil

Comment: This greatly helped me with the same situation.